# codeigniter MY_Controller not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, controllers, extending-classes

i’m using the Codeigniter.2.1.3 for a website, so i need to extend the CI_Controller so i can add a method to be executed with all controllers so i did what’s in the user_guide:

creating a file named MY_Controller.php in the application/core folder the creating in it MY_Controller Class that extends the CI_Controller, the changing my regular controller to extend the MY_controller like this:
MY_controller.php:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{
    protected $page;
    # Constructor
    function __construct (){
        parent::__construct();
        #code shared with all controllers
    }
    public function get_page(){
        #code to get_the right page here
    }
}
```

regular controller named Regular.php:

```
class Regular extends MY_Controller{
     public function __construct(){
         parent::__construct();
     }
     public function index(){
          $this->get_page();
     }
}
```

but the following error keep appearing:

> Fatal error: Class ‘MY_Controller’ not found in /var/www/immo/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/application/controllers/regular.php on line 2

Comment: In your application/config/config.php what do you have for `$config['subclass_prefix']`

Comment: Are you sure MY_Controller.php is in the application/core folder? Also if your on linux, things can be case sensitive :) Make sure the file name is the same as the controller name. `MY_Controller.php`, not `MY_controller.php`.

Comment: add  a space after MY_Controller

Comment: @Esailija $config['subclass_prefix'] = "MY_"

Comment: @Jeemusu: yes its in the application/core folder

Comment: @YahyaKACEM please turn log level to the max (set application/config/config.php `$config['log_threshold']` to 4) then make /application/logs writable and see  what happens in codeigniter

Comment: Try renaming your PHP file to `MY_controller.php` (lower case C) and placing it in your libraries folder `application/core` (sorry wrong path)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You would need to include your `MY_Controller` class or auto-load it.  I suggest you auto-load it by adding the following to your `application/config/config.php` file.

```
function __autoload($class)
{
    if (strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
    {
        if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . EXT))
        {
            include $file;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why do i need to do that when i extend a library i don't need to autoload it why this is different, and there's nothing about that in the documentations.

Comment: Here is the original article on the technique which was created by Phil Sturgeon - http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY

Comment: still not working now it gives me 2 new warnings: include_once(application/core/MY_Controller.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: include_once(): Failed opening 'application/core/MY_Controller.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/var/www/ZendFramework/library')

Comment: no idea whet that mean in the application/core there's the file MY_Controller.php and its readable.

Comment: Try to output the content of APPPATH and see if it does point to the right path.

Comment: And your `index.php` file is at the same level than your `application` folder?

Comment: this is so embarrassing it was just the wrong file name instead of MY_Controller.php i save the file with the name MY_Contorller.php and no need for the autoload function in the config file it’s already autoloaded. sorry for that and thanx for your help.

Comment: this autoload function is useful when you extends class more then 2 inheritance, I mean, just like in philsturgeon blog.

Comment: Deprecated: __autoload() is deprecated, use spl_autoload_register()

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the filename is perfectly cased. Linux server is case-sensitive. So if the class name is My_Controller then the name of the file should be My_Controller.php

Comment: It doesn't matter what the controller class name is inside. Just having `MY_Controller.php` will solve the problem. In my case, my controller's name is CRM_controller.. :)

Answer (score 3):

in **config/config.php**

```
/* load class in core folder */
function my_load($class) {        

    if (strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0) {            
        if (is_readable(APPPATH . 'core' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $class . '.php' )) {                
            require_once (APPPATH . 'core' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $class . '.php');                
        }
    }

}

spl_autoload_register('my_load');
```

Comment: Despite all the other solutions did kind of make sense, this is the only one that actually helped. I believe the Classes in the core folder don't  outoload in my case because I upgraded to CodeIgnitor 3.x from 2.x (but that needs to be confirmed) and I may have forgotten something during the process...

Answer (score 2):

`$config['subclass_prefix'] = "MY_"`

check that in `config.php` and of course you should use it in Controller Name Like `MY_Controller.php` and Named ***"class MY_Controller...."***

Answer (score 0):

Late with this answer, but I got the

> "Fatal error: Class ‘MY_Controller’ not found" error

when I had a controller (`.php`) file by the same name at the web root instead of the application/controllers directory.

Don't know how it got there, actually, but the problem went away when I deleted it.