# CodeIgniter Extended Core Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm stumped on this one.

With my CodeIgniter application set up on a WAMP server locally, everything is fine. All of my classes extend my controller (MY_Controller)

However, when the application is on the live environment which is Linux based, it throws an error that the MY_Controller class doesn't exist.

Have I forgot about a configuration variable somewhere or something like that with a path to the application/core folder?

I've looked for other threads with the same issue across Google, found a solution that worked for most people of using `parent::Controller();` instead of `parent::__construct()` but that doesn't resolve this for me.

Comment: Are you certain your controller is correctly placed in application/core, with the correct file name, class name and extends statement?

Comment: Yes, it is in the correct folder, correct file name (MY_Controller.php) and class name (MY_Controller) and works fine on the local WAMP server, the exact same code (minus some configuration constants) on the linux based server returns this error.

I've temporarily got around this by including the core controller in all controllers but it's not ideal.

Comment: Then gotta think on this one awhile. It *should* work... Also, parent::Controller(); is an alias of parent::__construct(), afaik. It should not affect functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that the case of the filename is incorrect (ex: My_controller instead of My_Controller) and your online environment is case sensitive and your local environment is case_insensitive. I've had that problem a lot

Comment: Oh yeah, you nailed this one, I think. WAMP is windows-based, right? So it wouldn't care what filename case you use.

Comment: That could be it - however, my standard controllers have lowercase filenames and uppercase class names (e.g. firstcontroller.php is the class FirstController) so why would this only affect the core controller?

Comment: No, if you wrote the names in the comment above exactly as they are in your project, you got it right.

Comment: Because that filename is not lowercase (MY_Controller.php)? Just a thought, often when i have errors online but not locally it has something to do with case-sensitivity

Comment: The case doesn't fix the issue

Comment: It's likely an issue of case sensitivity. Try doing your filename in all lowercase, and make sure the class name itself has the proper capitalization (`MY_Controller`).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for resurrecting an old post but this issue plagued me a little while ago.

I figured I'd add this link: [codeigniter MY_Controller not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483677/codeigniter-my-controller-not-found)

Just in-case there is a poor soul who's banging their head against the table and they haven't come across the above post before.

Thanks to Maxime Morin and Phil Sturgeon:

```
function __autoload($class)
{
    if (strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
    {
        if (file_exists($file = APPPATH . 'core/' . $class . EXT))
        {
            include $file;
        }
    }
}
```