# How can I get CodeIgniter 2.1.4 to load my extended Controller Class?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have looked for this answer all through stackoverflow and none have been able to help me.

my file name is: application/core/MY_Controller.php

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
        parent::__construct();

}

}
```

I made a post in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898601/codeigniter-extended-core-controller) asking if anyone had found an answer.  I tried everything in that thread, and in all suggested links.

I'm at a complete loss.

Everything works on my local WAMP server (apache 2.4 php 5.4) and not on the production server (Ubuntu 12.04, apache 2.4, php 5.5)

error:

> PHP Fatal error: Class 'MY_Controller' not found in filepath/application/controllers/welcome.php on line 7.

Line 7 is where I define the class: `class welcome extends MY_Controller {`

**EDIT**
Thanks for all the help.  I figured out what was wrong. 
When I initially started trying to figure out this problem, I noticed that I did not have my case right on the name of MY_Controller.php, it was My_Controller.php.

So, what I found out was that even though I changed the name of the file on my local machine, when I uploaded it, the name still didn't change.  So, when I went to change it to all lower case I decided to do that directly on the production server and found that after all this time it was still named with the lowercase y when I thought I had changed that.  I hope this helps anyone else who migrates from a WAMP environment to a LAMP environment to know that even though the case is changed, it is still the same name, and may or may not be changed when you upload it.

Comment: What URL are you using to attempt to access the controller? Keep in mind that Linux is case-sensitive while windows is not.

Comment: myurl/welcome

the welcome controller extends MY_Controller

Comment: What errors are you seeing?

Comment: PHP Fatal error: Class 'MY_Controller' not found in filepath/application/controllers/welcome.php on line 7.  Line 7 is where I define the class:  class welcome extends MY_Controller {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please go to your `application/config/config.php` and on the bottom insert this code

```
function __autoload($class)
{
 if(strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
 {
  @include_once( APPPATH . 'core/'. $class . EXT );
 }
}
```

Now you are good to go.

---

please try creating file MY_Controller.php in /core folder with this body

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
    }

}
```

and use welcome controller if it works.

---

I missed note: Everything works on my local WAMP server (apache 2.4 php 5.4) and not on the production server (Ubuntu 12.04, apache 2.4, php 5.5)

**Please check your case of files/controllers**

Please try editing/renaming everything in to lower case (even `my_controller extends CI_Controller`).

Comment: I've done that, and it didn't work.

I also tried this function spl_autoload_register(function ($class){ [your inner function coder here ]});

Comment: Why is this needed?  CodeIgniter should load core classes with the prefix `MY_` automatically.

Comment: I wondered myself, this works for me and I grabbed it from Phils tutorial http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY

Comment: I did place it in my core folder where it is suppose to be.

I also have checked my case through out and everything matches.

Comment: From what I am seeing, my MY_Controller.php is not getting loaded, and I don't know of anything else I can do to make it load.  I also found that I am having problems with loading helper files as well through $this->load->helper("some_helper");

Comment: Is folder readable by the user running the web server (apache)?