# Making controllers in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, constructor

I have some controller in Codeigniter like this

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();  
        // Load globals
        $data->mail = new phpmailer();
        $data->minified = new Minifier($vars_minified);
        $this->load->vars($data);


    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->home();
    }

    public function home()
    {


        $data['meta_title'] = seo::text($this->lang->line('home_title'), 70);


        $data['body_render']='view_home';
        $this->load->view("/layouts/view_layout", $data);
    }

}
```

This is Home controller, that has __construct
Now i want to make new controller like page, but problem is with contruct , do i must repeat __construct in that controller too, or i just can put it somehow that all controllers will us that contsruct?

This is page controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();  
        // Load globals
        $data->mail = new phpmailer();
        $data->minified = new Minifier($vars_minified);
        $this->load->vars($data);


    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->page();
    }

    public function page()
    {


        $data['meta_title'] = seo::text($this->lang->line('home_title'), 70);


        $data['body_render']='view_page';
            $this->load->view("/layouts/view_layout", $data);
    }

}
```

You see, i have again __construct at top, is it possible to get rid of it, and make one unique __construct?

Comment: Don't load things globally that you don't need everywhere and always within that controller!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible please follow this [guide](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY).

When done, you can set your __construct for all `Public_Controller`[s], `Admin_Controller`[s] etc.

It is exactly what you want.

Note that after this step your variables that you send to views are going to change a bit: from `$data['key']` , to `$this->data['key']`consider your data as "global" in scope of either Public_Controller or Admin_Controller etc.

If any troubles write a comment or read [this core extending guide by ellislab](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html) or this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22795533/1564365) where I mention this very same method.